# Using router public IP to access another (located in WAN) router behind NAT

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv6, wan, ipv4

I have following setup:

1. at home I have a router up and running with public ipv4 ip
2. at my country house I have ipv4 cam and router which is behind NAT - no public ip (public ip is too expensive)
3. both routers have custom firmware (ASUS WL-500 at 1 and DIR-320 at 2)

I want to be able to do two things:

1. access cam from anywhere via ipv4
2. surf internet at location 2 with handheld and portable devices (ipad, android phone, windows laptop)

Is it doable at all?
I was thinking about some weird ipv6 tunneling from 2 to 1 and port forwarding at location 1? Or maybe ssh tunneling can help?

Thank you for your answers. :)

**UPD 1** - added info about lack of public IP at 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is a (destination) port forwarding on the router at 2). Just point the ports you need to access the cam (port 80?) to the private IP of that cam. Then you need something like Dyndns to access your public IP at 2) with a domain name. This allows anybody (who knows your current IP or the domain name) to access the cam; so this should be secured.

Another option would be to setup a VPN between 1) and 2) if both routers allow you to do so.

Everything else needs more equipment to built up tunnels between 1) and 2). Either via SSH tunnel or VPN.

IPv6 won't solve any of your "problems". But with IPv6 you can achieve the same as with IPv4, so this doesn't change anything.

Comment: I should have stated it more clearly - I do not have public ip at location 2. A VPN is a good idea, thank you! Do you know how I can do that with *-WRT firmware?